# Why ain't all ions excluding alpha particle negatively charged?

Tags: atomic-physics, electric-fields

Suicide or not I seek your expert advice. Most textbooks agree that the nucleus consists of mainly proton or neutron or both "sit" at the center of electron cloud, since the electron shells are displaced around the nucleus how come there can be neutral or positive net charge in this case? I'm puzzled how the electric charge works for an electron cloud instead of point like particle?

Comment: Um: if there are less electrons than there are protons in the system then it is positively charged: if there are more, then it is negatively charged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, let me keep this post to a rather qualitative level with a few concepts that have certain limits but will serve in this case.
Let us say we have the nucleus, made up of protons and neutrons (or only one proton for hydrogen), in the middle and the electron cloud around it. From the outside, we do not see the single charges of electron cloud and nucleus, we see the net charge of both. And the net charge of both is given by $N_\textrm{protons}-N_\textrm{electrons}$ elementary charges. So it really depends on the number of both of them - but simple examples of positive ions are neutral atoms that by some mechanism loose an electron. Then, there is one more proton than there are electrons and the ion has an overall charge of $+1$.
That the electrons are in reality, due to quantum effects, no point particles, does not change their charge properties in any way and if we look from the outside at the atom and count charges, it does not really matter *where exactly* they are as long as they are "inside the atom".

Comment: So I shouldn't take Bohr model or the likes too literally.

Comment: no, indeed. Bohr's model is really nice because it gives an intuitive understanding of some main features, but it has its limits. Even the ordinary QM treatment has its limits and for a full treatment, we have to think about relativistic effects - but it is still valueable to have a basic picture as long as you are aware of its limits.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add slightly to @Sanya's answer:

> I'm puzzled how the electric charge works for an electron cloud instead of point like particle

I hope someone corrects me if I am wrong, but the electric charge is only associated with a particle/ definite  quanta of the electron field in [Quantum Field Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory), not with the "electron clouds", as these clouds could be viewed as the regions where the point particle is most likely to be found, rather than a physical "thing".

[image]

These are the d orbitals, and I hope  they give an impression of clouds within which,  when we perform an  observation/measurement, the electron, with it's associated electric charge, may most likely be found.